# Bash script unable to run (too many arguments)

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash    
if [ -e *.txt ]                                                                                                         then
            rm *.txt
            echo "removing previous files"
    else
            echo "files already deleted"
    fi
```

I'm trying to remove all txt files in my current directory if I have more than 1 txt file I get an error. Not quite sure whats happening.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have, say, two files 1.txt and 2.txt, your code basically leads to:

```
if [ -e 1.txt 2.txt ]
…
```

which just raises a syntax error, because `-e` expects a single argument.

You could rely on some CLI tool such as `find`, but maybe you don't need the `if` in the first place?

Namely something like:

```
rm -f *.txt
```

to avoid failing in case there is no `*.txt` file,

otherwise:

```
rm -f -v *.txt
```

if you also want to get some log of the removed files.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the `if ... fi` logic, there's no need for an `-e` test here.  Unix utils are themselves designed to return exit codes, and in this case it's simpler to test the result of `rm` itself:

```
if rm *.txt 2> /dev/null
then
    echo "removing previous files"
else
    echo "files already deleted"
fi
```

But even though it's not needed, do note that a separate test could be made to work like so:

```
if [ "$(ls *.txt)" ]
```

...or in pure `bash`, (no external util like `ls` needed), if we temporarilly set the *nullglob* option:

```
if (shopt -s nullglob; [ "$(echo *.txt)" ])
```

Comment: regarding the last remark of your answer, I'm not sure it'd work as `echo *.txt` prints `*.txt` litteraly if there is no `.txt` file (but maybe there's some Bash option to change that default behavior)

Comment: @ErikMD, Thanks for spotting that error!  Now revised with `s/echo/ls/`, which is lame, but it seems to work...

Comment: actually it seems there is a more builtin solution with Bash, using a special option − cf. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html − `shopt -s nullglob; if [ "$(echo *.txt)" ]; then echo "file(s) found"; fi`

Comment: @ErikMD, Good idea, see revised answer.